# setting user sesssion with user_id to shopping cart library in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter,ajax to develop shopping cart.

1)After login into user

2)i submitting items list (which is to purchase items) to cart

3)my issue is the submitted data is displaying same to all other users now, i need set user session with user_id into the cart library of codeigniter to display cart items to seperate seperate user.

**users home.php:**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){?>
            <div class="alert alert-success"><?php echo $_SESSION['loggedin'];?></div>
        <?php } ?>
        Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Item</th>
                <th class="text-center">Quantity</th>
                <th class="text-center">Price</th>
                <th class="text-center">Add</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($items as $item):?>
            <tr class="success">         
                <td><?php echo $item['product_name'];?></td>
                <td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="quantity" id="<?php echo $item['product_id'];?>" class="quantity" maxlength="2" size="2"></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['product_price'];?></td>
                <td><button type="button" name="add_cart" class="add_cart" data-productname="<?php echo $item['product_name'];?>" data-price="<?php echo $item['product_price'];?>" data-productid="<?php echo $item['product_id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1">
        <div id="cart_details" class="text-center">
            <h3>Cart is Empty</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add_cart').click(function(){
    var product_id=$(this).data("productid");
    var product_name=$(this).data("productname");
    var product_price=$(this).data("price");
    var quantity=$('#' + product_id).val();
        if(quantity != '' && quantity >0){
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url();?>users/add",
                method:"POST",
                data:{product_id:product_id,product_name:product_name,product_price:product_price ,quantity :quantity},
                success:function(data)
                {
                alert("Product Added into cart");
                $('#cart_details').html(data);
                $('#' + product_id).val('');
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Please Enter Quantity");
        }
    });
    $('#cart_details').load("<?php echo base_url();?>users/load");

    $(document).on('click','.remove_inventory',function(){
        var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete item")){
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url();?>users/remove",
                method:"POST",
                data:{row_id:row_id},
                success:function(data)
                {
                alert("Product remove fromm cart");
                $('#cart_details').html(data);
                }
            });
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

**controller.php**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller 
{  
    public function index($page='home')
    {
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/users/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('');
        }
        $data['title']=ucfirst($page);
        $data['items'] = $this->user_item->get_items();

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('users/'.$page,$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function add()
    {
        $this->load->library('cart');
        $data = array(
            'id' => $_POST["product_id"],
            'name' => $_POST["product_name"],
            'qty' => $_POST["quantity"],
            'price' => $_POST["product_price"],   
        );
        $this->cart->insert($data); //return rowid
        echo $this->view();
    }

    public function load()
    {
        echo $this->view();
    }

    public function remove()
    {
        $this->load->library('cart');
        $row_id = $_POST["row_id"];
        $data = array(
            'rowid' => $row_id,
            'qty' => 0
        );
        $this->cart->update($data); 
        echo $this->view();
    }

    public function view()
    {
        $this->load->library('cart');
        $output = '';
        $output.='
        <h3>Shopping cart</h3><br/>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div align="right">
            <button type="button" id="clear_cart" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
            <br/>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Quantity</th>
            <th class="text-center">Price</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
            </tr>
        ';
        $count = 0;
        foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items){
            $count++;
            $output .='
            <tr>
                <td>'.$items["name"].'</td>
                <td>'.$items["qty"].'</td>
                <td>'.$items["price"].'</td>
                <td>'.$items["subtotal"].'</td>
                <td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_inventory" id="'.$items["rowid"].'"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }
        $output .='
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>
                <td>'.$this->cart->total().'</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
        ';
        if($count == 0){
            $output = '<h3 align="center">cart is empty</h3>';
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

**model.php**

```
<?php
class User_item extends CI_Model
{
    public function __contruct()
    {
        $this->load-database();
    }

    public function get_items($ItemCode = FALSE)
    {
        if($ItemCode === FALSE)
            {
                $query = $this->db->get('tblItems');
                return $query->result_array();
            }
        $query = $this->db->get_where('tblItems',array('ItemCode' => $ItemCode));
        return $query->row_array();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Model does not seem to filter the items based on the user who sent the request, looks to me as if you are fetching the same items from the DB for every user's request when using this code

```
$this->db->get('tblItems');
```

Perform filtering of items per user, maybe using a clause such as

```
$this->db->get_where('tblItems', array('user_id' => $userID));
```

Based on a user's unique ID and a join with a user's table somewhere

Comment: in tblItems table we have to add userid column?

Comment: You have to find a way to link the item to the user. Adding a user column is one way, but a better way would be to create a separate table having the user ID and item ID together as the PK (normalization stuff), then when selecting you can filter out items belonging to a specific user using table joins

Comment: here am trying to insert items into cart library of codeigniter. we cann't store userId in cart @Peter

Comment: Assuming you cannot do so, how do you link a cart to a specific user @AnishKumarRamagiri? Or how do you know which user selected which items?

Comment: so, we should not use cart library instead we have to create table to cart. yes @peter M

Comment: The issue is not the cart lib, the problem is how you have designed your app to link a cart to a user. You should instead ask yourself, "how do I know which user selected which items?" then you can be able to select that user's cart and items. Have a look at shopping cart examples online and see how they do it

Comment: can u suggest links to go through it thanking u advance